# Setting up a private network with one node per VM with TestRPC?

Tags: go-ethereum, testnets, testrpc

I wonder if I can set up a private test network with 4 nodes (4 Linux VMs) on the same network with testRPC.

TestRPC is really easy to use (create a blockchain, no need of mining etc etc) when developping smart contracts.

I know that geth is capable of creating a private test network with multiple nodes, but wonder if testRPC is also capable of achieving this task.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3):

I believe testRPC just gives you a "feel" of the original blockchain and is used on a single system to experiment how the blockchain works(includes RPC functions), and build Ethereum applications without spending real Ether. Everything is configured beforehand.

It's designed just for application development and cannot be used for operations like connecting nodes, creating accounts(after startup), mining, syncing blockchain etc.

Comment: Thanks for strengthen my idea. After some more readings, I draw the same conclusion as you.